# Site url is not showing the home page

Tags: pages, urls, homepage

Marraxxxx.online is my website url, when i go to it, it gives me blanc page,

only when i go to Marraxxxx.online/home the proper home page shows up correctly, how i can solve this plz? I want the official Marraxxxx.online shows the proper home page.

Marraxxxx.online/home is a page in the main menu, so blanc page appears first for my visitors, then they must click Home on the main menu to see the proper home page,

Any solution plz,
Thanks

Comment: Have you gone to Settings > Reading and set "Your homepage displays" to "A static page" and selected the page?

Comment: Yes, many times but in vain. Finally, i solved by installing a free plugin called "Simple Website Redirect". It did not seem to work in the beginning, but after few hours the effects took place. This plugin redirects internal url to whatever destination y choose. It takes few hours for the changes to take place.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i solved by installing a free plugin called "Simple Website Redirect". It did not seem to work in the beginning, but after few hours the effects took place. This plugin redirects internal url to whatever destination y choose. It takes few hours for the changes to take place.